# UILabel animate change of portion of text

Tags: swift, animation, text, uilabel

I want to be able to animate the following label "Your score: 22" the way that when you earn one more score, the part '22' bounces up down quickly and becomes 23. I could not find anything sensible except making multiple labels, but it's a horrible solution.

Comment: I don't know that having a separate label is horrible.  It's simple and it will work!

Comment: @DJohnson the drawback of using that method is that I am actively using UILabel's property 'adjustFontToFit', for example if score is 999999 then it will shrink the label while conserving reasonable spacing between characters. Doing the same with multiple labels is a mess

Comment: @GrishaGevorkyan are you finding something like [this](http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/iphone-game-scoreboard-using-core-animation/) ?

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/daveverwer/SDScoreBoard) the demo you are finding ...

Comment: @Sneha thank you, but it uses images as digits.

Comment: Not a big deal@GrishaGevorkyan, Link all Images to a Digit & then Use it with your code.. So simple....!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late answer but in case, Others want this time of Functionality then may be useful..

https://github.com/suzuki-0000/CountdownLabel

The demo project is in Swift But there's also given .h file for Objective C use..

So in both language, Swift & Objective C, we can implement it.